# Getting Message Attachments from Teams Action-Based Messaging Extension?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm working on an action-based messaging extension. I have code getting the list of attachments from the message that the action was invoked from, but I'm stuck on actually being able to get the attachment file.

I found code over here that looks good:
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4466

```
var attachment = turnContext.Activity.Attachments.First();
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    // Skype & MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
    if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.Equals("skype", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.Equals("msteams", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var token = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials().GetTokenAsync();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    }

    var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);
    var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Attachment of {attachment.ContentType} type and size of {contentLenghtBytes} bytes received.");
}
```

But I'm unclear about the line for getting the token. First, MicrosoftAppCredentials doesn't have an empty constructor. If I try it using my bot app's ID and secret, when I try to get the content, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

I can understand that to use ContentUrl, I should need to pass a token, but I'm unclear--what kind of token do I need and how do I get it in my code?

**EDIT:**
The payload I get from clicking my action in "More Actions" from a message containing a file is:

```
{
  "value": {
    "commandId": "doCommand",
    "commandContext": "message",
    "messagePayload": {
      "id": "1571645922015",
      "replyToId": null,
      "createdDateTime": "2019-10-21T08:18:42.015Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": null,
      "deleted": false,
      "subject": "",
      "summary": null,
      "importance": "normal",
      "locale": "en-us",
      "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": "Test with attachment<attachment id=\"4CBC1114-02B6-4FB5-87D4-63048312B0EC\"></attachment>"
      },
      "from": {
        "device": null,
        "conversation": null,
        "user": {
          "userIdentityType": "aadUser",
          "id": "e291b04a-f0d8-43e8-829a-499e644005e1",
          "displayName": "Amy Thorne"
        },
        "application": null
      },
      "reactions": [],
      "mentions": [],
      "attachments": [
        {
          "id": "581E8D22-2955-4DD4-8594-90F92F6737CB",
          "contentType": "reference",
          "contentUrl": "https://amythorneco.sharepoint.com/sites/AmysTeam/Shared Documents/General/Test.txt",
          "content": null,
          "name": "Test.txt",
          "thumbnailUrl": null
        }
      ]
    },
    "context": { "theme": "default" }
  },
  "conversation": { "id": "19:b7082f7e8a2547d49e0c730b9566fded@thread.skype;messageid=1571645922015" },
  "name": "composeExtension/fetchTask",
  "imdisplayname": "Amy Thorne"
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [Authentication for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-bot-aad) to get the token. Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) that might help you. Please let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: For implementing authentication, my problem is I'm not sure what resource or scopes I need the authenticated entity to have. For example, I tried having an Azure AD app registration with application access to Sites.FullControl.All and using a token for that, but I still got 401 Unauthorized. What permissions are required for code to use that URL?

Comment: You don't need an auth token to get the attachment file. Could you please try getting the content url without using the token?

Comment: Without using the token, I get 403 Forbidden

Comment: What is the payload you are getting when you click on "More Actions" from a message containing a file?

Comment: I edited my post above to include the payload.

Comment: Are you trying to get the content url for the file? I could see that you are able to get the contentURL in the payload? What is it you are looking for?

Comment: I want to download the file within the code for the messaging extension. When I try to use HttpClient to get the file content at the contentUrl, if I pass no token, I receive 403 Forbidden. I assume I need to pass a token, but I'm having trouble understanding what kind of a token I need, for what resources or scopes. How do I obtain the correct token for that request?

Comment: @AmyT, did you find a solution eventually? I'm looking at the same problem and my bot is written in Typescript